Надо ли поставить запятую?
Будешь плохо выполнять это задание — закончишь(,) как он.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в данном случае при сравнительном обороте, или здесь сравнительный оборот тесно связан со сказуемым?

Правильно:
Будешь плохо выполнять это задание — // закончишь, как он.
Пояснение

Это БСП, отношения между частями предложения взаимообусловленные, пауза обозначена тире.

Оборот как он является сравнительным, обстоятельственного значения не имеет и поэтому обособляется.

Интонационно предложение делится на две части, поэтому может показаться, что сравнительный оборот тесно связан со сказуемым  (пауза перед оборотом произносительная).


